# Pyaudio не добавляется в компиляции Nuitka

Tags: python, python-3.x, nuitka

Компилирую свой файл с помощью Nuitka, добавив к нему пакет pyaudio:

```
python -m nuitka --module main.py --include-package=pyaudio
```

После компиляции запускаю свой .pyd через C++ и вижу ошибку:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio._portaudio'
```

Как я понимаю - pyaudio добавился, ошибок в компиляции не было. Но класс из pyaudio нет, что делать?
В интернете искал похожие ошибки, но не нашел